# R dplyr pivot to long form while removing repeated elements

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, pivot

I have a data frame that looks like so:

```
  |  id   |  nct_id    |minimum_age| maximum_age |criteria_rank |   criteria                             
1 |6516355| NCT04293180| 2 Years |     50 Years|    Inclusion Criteria_1| criteria 1 description
2 |6516355| NCT04293180| 2 Years |     50 Years|    Inclusion Criteria_2| criteria 2 description
3 |6516355| NCT04293180| 2 Years |     50 Years|    Exclusion Criteria_1| criteria 3 description
4 |6531830| NCT04091700| 18 Years|    45 Years |    Inclusion Criteria_1| criteria 1 description
5 |6531830| NCT04091700| 18 Years|    45 Years |    Inclusion Criteria_2| criteria 2 description
6 |6531830| NCT04091700| 18 Years|    45 Years |    Exclusion Criteria_1| criteria 3 description
7 |6531830| NCT04091700| 18 Years|    45 Years |    Exclusion Criteria_2| criteria 4 description
```

I want to transpose this into a data frame that looks like so:

```
  |V1                  |                V2       |              V3           |          
1 |id                  |              6516355    |             6531830       |        
2 |nct_id              |              NCT04293185|            NCT04091737    |        
3 |minimum_age         |           2 Years       |              18 Years     |         
4 |maximum_age         |           50 Years      |              45 Years     |         
5 |Inclusion Criteria_1| criteria 1 description. | criteria 1 description.   |
6 |Inclusion Criteria_2| criteria 2 description. | criteria 2 description.   |
7 |Exclusion Criteria_1| criteria 3 description. | criteria 3 description.   |
8 |Exclusion Criteria_2| NA                      | criteria 4 description.   |
```

Basically I want to pivot the data frame to a long form and get rid of the common repeating elements while keeping the Inclusion and exclusion criteria. This is just a sample of the data but I have several nct_id's and the number of inclusion and exclusion criteria vary for each nct _id so the nct_id with the most inclusion exclusion criteria will drive how many inclusion exclusion criteria rows are created. nct_id's that have fewer inclusion/exclusion criteria will have NA filled in (as shown in the last row of the example). In this instance the first column has the row names.

Having trouble figuring it out. Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Sample data is here:

```
structure(list(id = c(6516355, 6516355, 6516355, 6531830, 6531830, 
6531830, 6531830), nct_id = c("NCT04293180", "NCT04293180", "NCT04293180", 
"NCT04091700", "NCT04091700", "NCT04091700", "NCT04091700"), 
    minimum_age = c("2 Years", "2 Years", "2 Years", "18 Years", 
    "18 Years", "18 Years", "18 Years"), maximum_age = c("50 Years", 
    "50 Years", "50 Years", "45 Years", "45 Years", "45 Years", 
    "45 Years"), criteria_rank = c("Inclusion Criteria_1", "Inclusion Criteria_2", 
    "Exclusion Criteria_1", "Inclusion Criteria_1", "Inclusion Criteria_2", 
    "Exclusion Criteria_1", "Exclusion Criteria_2"), criteria = c("criteria 1 description", 
    "criteria 2 description", "criteria 3 description", "criteria 1 description", 
    "criteria 2 description", "criteria 3 description", "criteria 4 description"
    )), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), nct_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), minimum_age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), maximum_age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), criteria_rank = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), criteria = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly with column names `V1`, `V2`, `V3` - Here I use the `id` as column names for each record while the name of attributes stored in `variables` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%   
  # to remove criteria_rank and store the criteria description under
  # values of of criteria_rank instead.
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, nct_id, minimum_age, maximum_age),
             names_from = "criteria_rank", values_from = "criteria") %>%
  # Put data in long format where all the criteria is store in variables column
  # and thier values store in values column
  pivot_longer(names_to = "variables", values_to = "values",
               cols = c("nct_id", "maximum_age", "minimum_age") |
                 contains("Criteria")) %>%
  # convert data into wide format with the id is column name
  pivot_wider(id_cols = variables, names_from = "id", values_from = "values")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  variables            `6516355`              `6531830`             
  <chr>                <chr>                  <chr>                 
1 nct_id               NCT04293180            NCT04091700           
2 maximum_age          50 Years               45 Years              
3 minimum_age          2 Years                18 Years              
4 Inclusion Criteria_1 criteria 1 description criteria 1 description
5 Inclusion Criteria_2 criteria 2 description criteria 2 description
6 Exclusion Criteria_1 criteria 3 description criteria 3 description
7 Exclusion Criteria_2 NA                     criteria 4 description
```